# Адаптивное лого с меню

Tags: css3

Есть картинка и меню.При сжатии меню лезет на логотип.Как можно исправить?

```css
    .fix {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-center {
  text-align: center;
  @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    .fix {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: inherit;
    }
    .img-center {
      float: left;
    }
    .header {
      height: 55px;
      background-color: #333;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="fix">

  <div class="img-center">
    <a href=""><img src=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <input class="nav-burger__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="burger">
      <label class="nav-burger" for="burger">Меню</label>
      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__item" href="#">1</a>
        <a class="nav__item" href="#">2</a>
        <a class="nav__item" href="#">3</a>
        <a class="nav__item" href="#">4</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Наезжает из-за  float, и вы задаете стили `header` а у вас прокладка еще есть `container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь вы это имели в виду

```css
.fix{
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        background: white;
        z-index: 1;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .img-center {
        text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px){
.fix{
    position:absolute;
    text-align: inherit;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;

}
.img-center{
        float: left;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    }
.header {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="fix">

<div class="img-center">

<a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/55
"></a>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<input class="nav-burger__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="burger">
<label class="nav-burger" for="burger">Меню</label>

  <nav class="nav">
    <a class="nav__item" href="#"></a>
    <a class="nav__item" href="#"></a>
    <a class="nav__item" href="#"></a>
    <a class="nav__item" href="#"></a>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
```